# how to set a starting page in a ionic project

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

Sorry if this is a stupid question I am still fairly new to this. I have a basic understanding of how the navigation works with angular js but I cant figure out how to set a starting page. I want to set my login page as my start page the url shows that the login page is open ("http://localhost:8100/#/template/login") but it only displays a blank header which I suspect is from my index (ion-nav-bar).

thank you.

index.html

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view class="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

login.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" name="login-view">
  <ion-content class="padding">
  <h1>lalalalala</h1>
     <div class="list">
         <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Username</span>
              <input type="text">
         </label>
         <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Password</span>
              <input type="password">
         </label>
      </div>
      <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

.state('tab.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'login': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.projects', {
      url: '/projects',
      views: {
        'tab-projects': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-projects.html',
          controller: 'projectsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.projects-detail', {
      url: '/projects/:projectsId',
      views: {
        'tab-projects': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/projects-detail.html',
          controller: 'projectsDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');

});
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('projectsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {
  $scope.chats = Chats.all();
  $scope.remove = function(chat) {
    Chats.remove(chat);
  }
})

.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats) {
  $scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId);
})

.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    enableFriends: true
  };
});
```

Comment: Do you want to show login page inside tabs? Can post what errors you are getting at console.

Comment: no I want to show the login at start up and after login is successful it needs to show the tabs @Codelord

Comment: Put the ```abstract``` view.

Comment: Another important thing, you have in mess once you declare your controllers, try to follow a guide like [this](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide), at least declare your controllers/services/directives and so on in the same way, ```LoginCtrl``` and not ```loginCtrl``` and the other stuff with no capital as a first letter. It is just an advise my friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the problems is in your default route:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/login');
```

You have defined it depending from the abastract **tab**:

```
$stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
  .state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })
```

and this is your login:

```
.state('tab.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'login': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

the state name is **tab.login** which means it inherits from **tab**.

so your root is **/tab/login**.

this should be your **tabs.html**:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <ion-tab title="Login" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/login">
    <ion-nav-view name="login"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Status" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/dash">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

as you can see your ion-nav-view name:

```
<ion-nav-view name="login"></ion-nav-view>
```

must match the one defined in your state:

```
.state('tab.login', {
        url: '/login',
        views: {
          'login': {
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
```

You don't need to set the view's name here (**login.html**):

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" name="login-view">
```

Another thing I've noticed, you use the same **name** for two different views: `tab-projects`:

```
.state('tab.projects', {
      url: '/projects',
      views: {
        'tab-projects': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-projects.html',
          controller: 'projectsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
.state('tab.projects-detail', {
      url: '/projects/:projectsId',
      views: {
        'tab-projects': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/projects-detail.html',
          controller: 'projectsDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

another thing has more to do with conventions. If you use for your views names starting with **tab-**, probably you should do the same for the **login**.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LSlydFKl64pyvTGmEqeW?p=preview) with some of your code.

Comment: Your answer works! my problem was with the inheritence "tab.login" and the reference in the tabs.html, thank you for the clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Change your app.js to

```
.state('login', {
   url: '/login',
   controller: 'LoginCtrl',
   templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
})
```

and  `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');`

If you place your `login.html` in correct folder then there is not going to be any problem.

Comment: I like this one, the ```otherwise``` method will always redirect to ```/login``` in case that any other route it's been matched. @Codelord

Answer (score 2):

I've been putting comments regarding your code, so let me formulate an answer with some steps you would like to follow

1:

You have a mess once you declare your controllers, try to follow a guide like [this](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide), at least declare your controllers/services/directives and so on in the same way, `LoginCtrl` and not `loginCtrl` and the other stuff with no capital as a first letter. It is just an advise my friend.

2:

```
.state('tab.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'login': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

here something you need to check, the name of your view, you have `login` but

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" name="login-view">
  ...
</ion-view>
```

so change it to `login` only. And do the same in your `abstract` route.

like this

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" name="login">
```

And this so important

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

which goes at the end of the `$stateProvider`. The `otherwise` method will always redirect to `/login` in case that any other route it's been matched

Comment: Thank you for the advice I will change my declarations as you said. @NietzcheProgrammer

Answer (score 1):

You should give a name to your `<ion-nav-view>` in your `index.html` template.

e.g. `<ion-nav-view name="viewContent"></ion-nav-view>`

Then, in your routes, you specify into which part of your app you want your template to be rendered, e.g.:

```
.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'viewContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

this will render `templates/login.html` into the `viewContent` area.
That's why UI-router is so flexible, because you can tell it exactly which parts should be replaced when routing.

If you don't need that flexibility, just write your routes without the `views` part and add `controller` and `templateUrl` directly to each state.

also your fallback probably should be `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');`

Comment: thanks for the explanation it cleared up some issues I had, but it still only shows a header and not the login content. I dont know if I am missing something? @tmaximini

Comment: first of all, it is weird that your url is "http://localhost:8100/#/template/login" - it should be "http://localhost:8100/#/login". also your fallback probably should be $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login'); Is there any error message in chrome dev tools?

Comment: also this might be related as you are also using the tabs starter: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22514999/532102

Comment: Don't forget to add has-header to your ion-content, sometimes your header can hide your content :
                 <ion-content class="has-header">
                              // your login content
                 </ion-content>

Comment: I am not receiving any errors at all, I did the fallback as you said but it still shows "http://localhost:8100/#/template/login" also does it make a difference when it shows the template directory as well?  to me it would make sense, because login is located in the templates folder. also is there any known bugs when testing in the browser using ionic-framework?  @tmaximini

Answer (score 0):

If you want to evaluate a success at login to show certain views should not be in the same state.

This should be true:

```
.state('login',{
  url: "/login",
  views : {
    'menuContent' : {
      templateUrl : "login.html",
      controller : "LoginCtrl"
    }
  }
})

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
```

Follow the order as advice or guide on how to write their app.js

```
<script id="login.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Login" name="login-view">
  <ion-content class="padding">
  <h1>lalalalala</h1>
  <div class="list">
     <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Username</span>
          <input type="text">
     </label>
     <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Password</span>
          <input type="password">
     </label>
  </div>
  <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
</script>
```

Comment: I have been using this coding but my main problem still remains, the content of my login page does not show. @sioesi

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem..simply open your app.js file..then right at the bottom you will find  `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/tabs');` so for instance if the page thats currently loading is "tabs"
simply change the value tabs to your prefered page name inorder for that page to load as the first default page.

Answer (score 0):

There is config.xml file. Open it and and you will see 'Start Page' Option. Then enter any page you want to start.

Comment: A line of code would be a perfect supplement of this answer